# How to render links in my CharField/TextField DB column as HTML in Django

Tags: html, django, django-templates

A snippet of my template -

```
{% block content %}
    {{ message.subject }}
    {{ message.content }}
{% endblock %}
```

My message.content = `" Check this out - /<a href="http://RigWave.In"> RigWave </a> "`

If you want to render as HTML (as a link) like this -

" Check this out -  [RigWave](http://RigWave.In)  "

Comment: wait what? I read this like 5 times... What you want to do? From DB take `[a href="http://RigWave.In"] RigWave [/a]` and replace [] to <>?

Comment: no sorry, i couldn't use <> coz SO was rendering it as a link

Comment: I think I may be wanting a custom template filter of some kind.

Comment: What do you know, I had a sneaking suspicion as such. Read my answer -- just use the "safe" filter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After looking at your unedited post, I'm wondering if you replaced the link tags with [ to prevent SO from rendering it as a link (though `` takes care of it).

If you actually have properly formatted links in the CharField, you need to [mark the string as safe](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#safe) to prevent auto HTML escaping.

```
{{ message.content|safe }}
```

or

```
{% autoescape off %}
    {{ body }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: You're the  man  Yuji! You always answer my questions. You feel me man!

Comment: I've never answered a question for user677990 :P Do you keep making new accounts?

Comment: I'm Sussagittikasusa, my account got banned for 2 weeks : [, I don't even know why.

Comment: This trick saved me when trying to programmatically create a large html table in the background using pandas, I just passed the whole thing through from my model field as a string and had the template render it. This is gold!

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters first sample is perfect, you could use custom filter or use `.replace`